# Translation of mild, medium, and hot (food spiciness)

Tags: traducción, adjetivos, comida, vocabulario

In English, salsa, hot sauce, or other spicy foods are often classified as either mild (not very spicy), medium (moderately spicy), or hot (very spicy). Does Spanish have similar adjectives to describe the range of spiciness of food?

Comment: Even though the answer you selected works for any Spanish speaking country bare in mind that you will hear different ways of referring to the same thing since this will depend a lot of the region/city/country.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a common way of speaking about spiciness

> **poco/ligeramente picante**- mild
>
> **picante** - medium
>
> **muy picante** - hot

If something is not spicy or slightly spicy we would say it is "**suave**".

Answer (score 2):

For years in South Texas my Mexican friends would say Muy Milo for very mild? I cannot find that referred to anywhere as a real word?

Comment: @DorothyHall: I would be careful with the use of this term since it might be (emphasis on "might") a "creation" of Mexicans living in the US. Another less likely possibility is that it may be used on a specific region of the country but I have never heard it, never in Mexico City where I'm from nor anywhere else and I did travel a lot within the country while I lived there.

Comment: Not a word used in Mexico at least

Answer (score 2):

Suave, mediana, and muy picante would be understood, provided the context makes the reference to spiciness obvious.  Example: one word on the label of a salsa jar,  the sort of word that's red for hot, yellow for medium, and green for mild.

Answer (score 1):

I would use:

> leve - mild
>
> medio - medium
>
> muy picante - hot

Comment: I'd use "poco/ligeramente picante", "picante" and "muy picante". "leve" and "medio" are not natural ways for speaking about spiciness. If something is not spicy or slightly spicy we would say it is "suave".

Comment: My native friend from Peru also suggested the translations I gave. Maybe a regional thing?

Comment: I am with juanillo on this one: ligeramente picante, picante y muy picante are more appropriate than 'medio'. Medio sounds more like an americanization of the term.

Comment: @Juanillo: Feel free to post another answer with your suggestions so people can up/down vote those as well.